# Why the same C++ library has much smaller size in static build than shared build, and static is not working while shared works?

Tags: android, c++, qt, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have problem when I try to use C++ library in Android studio project.

I am using **statically** built **Qt 5.14.2 for Android**.
I have **Qt library project** which has only 1 class with this 2 functions:

`testclass.h`

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C"
{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_MyTestAndroidApp_LibraryClass_log();

    void logNormal();
}
```

`testclass.cpp`

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_MyTestAndroidApp_LibraryClass_log()
{
    qDebug() << "---> log from Qt library";
}

void logNormal()
{
    qDebug() << "---> log from Qt library";
}
```

An in the `.pro` file I am using `shared` or `staticlib`  to switch from **shared(.so)** and **static(.a)** library.

```
TEMPLATE = lib
CONFIG += shared
#CONFIG += staticlib
CONFIG += c++11
```

After successfully building the lib (shared and static) I got this files(for ABI x86 but others ABIS have similar sizes too):

**libTestLibrary.so** ---> **3,359** **KB**

**libTestLibrary.a**  ---> **7** **KB**

For the **shared (.so) library** I was able to successfully call the function from android app.
In Android Studio I am creating new **Native C++** project. I have Java JNI **LibraryClas** which is used to load the library and call the **log()** function from the library. I placed the library in `jniLibs` folder.

But for the **static(.a)** library there are a lot of problems. I tried to call the logNormal() function from the C++ part of the android app(from `native-lib.cpp`). I am not using JNI like in the shared library case. Here is what I tried:

1. Create new Native C++ project
2. Created `libs`(for the static library) and `include`(for testclass.h) folders inside `app\src\main\cpp`
3. Inside `CMakeList.txt` I have added this:

`add_library(TestLibrary STATIC IMPORTED)`

`set_target_properties(TestLibrary PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libTestLibrary.a)`

`target_link_libraries( native-lib TestLibrary ${log-lib} )`

4. And I called **logNormal();** from `native-lib.cpp`.

First I got Error about missing Qt5Core library. After adding it the same way like my library I got errors for others missing libraries and files.

I have this questions:

1. Why **static** library is so much smaller then the **shared** library? **(7KB vs 3,359KB)** I found [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-static-and-shared-libraries/) which is opposite from my case:

[image]

2. Can I somehow build my static lib with all libraries and files that it need, so I don't get errors for missing libraries?
3. Can I use JNI to call C++ functions from static lib? Or when calling C++ functions from static lib it must be done from the C++ part of the android project?

Sorry for the long post and more then 1 question. Any hint or help is welcome. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: A static library is just an archive container of object files.  It should be the same size as the object files plus a little extra metadata (like the object file's name).

Comment: @Eljay thanks for comment, So static library can not include other libraries and files that it need to work. It just has the object files. And I will need to include those libraries in the project where I am actually using the static lib?

Comment: Correct, it's just a collection of object files, as a container file.  If 10 objects files each have `std::string`, then the `std::string` RTTI is duplicated in each separate object file.  A shared library has been linked, so duplicate information is culled out, and possibly some late toolchain optimizations can happen to further reduce the size and improve the performance.  And if there is debug information, it may have been stripped out.

Comment: and the shared library is including "what it needs" in order to run without problems?  In this case some "parts" from libQt5Core library because qDebug() is working. Right?

Comment: The shared library will contain information on dependencies but not the dependencies themselves. For example, it might have an undefined symbol for qDebug() and a DT_NEEDED entry for libqt5core.so.5.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb `will contain information on dependencies but not the dependencies themselves` , but how when I run it on android device(there is not qt core there)  qdebug works? it must be included from the shared library right? Like you mentioned for example it is including libqt5core.so.5?

Comment: If you install your app on an Android device using an APK, the dependencies lib libqtcore.so are usually installed as a part of that.  The DT_NEEDED entry is just a string saying "libqt5core.so.5" and it's up to the runtime loader to find that DSO and load it in to memory and resolve undefined symbols.

Comment: now i understand it, thanks for your time

Comment: @peco Is it possible that you answer your own question to explain the problem?